# Navigation bar event issue

Tags: iphone, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a navigation bar which have a custom button that button click event have a custom pop up menu, that have a table when i click a table row didselectrowatindexpath method not call.

I am using this code please resolve this

**Enter code here**

```
-(void)backButtonClicked1



{


    // create and configure the view
    CGRect cgRct = CGRectMake(220, 30, 93, 135); //define size and position of view 
    
    myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cgRct];

    myView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    [myView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    
     UIButton *btnpop=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 93, 140)];
    
     [btnpop setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [btnpop setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"popupbg@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [myView addSubview:btnpop];
    
    //[self.navigationController.navigationBar bringSubviewToFront:myView];

  // [myView release];
    
   
    table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1,20,90,114) 

style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    [table setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    table.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    table.separatorColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"popupline@2x.png"]];

    table.scrollEnabled=NO;

    table.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

    table.layer.borderWidth=1.0;

    table.layer.cornerRadius = 4;

    [table setDataSource:self];

    [table setDelegate:self];

    
    [myView addSubview:table];

    myView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;  
    //allow it to tweak size of elements in view 
    
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:myView];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar bringSubviewToFront:table];

    
 }
```

Comment: I don't see anything about didselectrowatindexpath in your provided code, care to upload it?

Answer (score 2):

You should add this

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Do your code here...

}
```

method on the corresponding .m class.

Answer (score 1):

As you have written delegate = self  & datasource = self then you suppose to write your delegate & datasource  methods inside that self class.

Please implement

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Do your code here...

}
```